# How can I place JButton over a JLabel with image?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I use NetBeans IDE to create an application using java. I want to include a `JButton` over a `JLabel` with image. Actually when I add `JButton` over the `JLabel` it would inserted but it will transparent and the name and the button didn't display. It seems the button to be added under the `JLabel`. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: So, what are you really trying to accomplish here? Layering components isn't that easy in Swing. For more information, see [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

Comment: **first**, show us what you have tried, **second** Make an image depicting your requirement, upload it to some image hosting site and link it in your question.

Comment: Im using JLayeredPane if you wanna keep it simple :)

Comment: You can create a JButton with an image, so what is the JLabel doing for you?

Comment: An example is shown **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198298/show-button-on-jlabel-in-swing/19198871#19198871)**. You should choose a proper layout manager based on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

there are two ways

1. put image to `JPanel` by override `paintComponent` (standard way)
2. `JLabel` haven't any `LayoutManager` in API, you have to set `LayoutManager`,  then `JLabel` will be container

Comment: +1 for suggestions. I think the problem OP is facing is about missing `JLabel`'s layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon img = null;
class Panel extends JPanel{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        if (img == null){
            img = new ImageIcon("d:\\picture.jpg");
             g.drawImage(img.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        }            
    }
}

//in the constructor
JButton button = new JButton( "OK");
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.add(button);
add(panel);
```